# FIWARE - iotagent-node-lib support for ngsiVersion "ld"

Tags: fiware, fiware-scorpio

I am trying to create an IoT Agent that uses NGSI-LD northbound to interact with an NGSI-LD Context Broker (Scorpio in this case)

In the latest release of iotagent-node-lib (2.14.0) it looks like it only includes support for v1 and v2 interactions with a Context Broker, e.g. in the deviceService:

```
function createInitialEntity(deviceData, newDevice, callback) {
    if (config.checkNgsi2()) {
        createInitialEntityNgsi2(deviceData, newDevice, callback);
    } else {
        createInitialEntityNgsi1(deviceData, newDevice, callback);
    }
}
```

but in the master branch it looks like there is support for v1, v2, mixed mode and ngsi-ld, e.g:

```
function init() {
    switch (config.ngsiVersion()) {
        case 'ld':
            deviceHandler = require('./devices-NGSI-LD');
            break;
        case 'v2':
            deviceHandler = require('./devices-NGSI-v2');
            break;
        case 'mixed':
            deviceHandler = require('./devices-NGSI-mixed');
            break;
        default:
            deviceHandler = require('./devices-NGSI-v1');
    }
}
function createInitialEntity(deviceData, newDevice, callback) {
    deviceHandler.createInitialEntity(deviceData, newDevice, callback);
}
```

Can you say when a release will include support for ngsi-ld interactions with context brokers? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, NGSI-LD support has been [merged recently](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/commit/8a98ad13164d7efaac1fee89201589a35199c27e) into the main branch of the IoT Agent node lib. So you will already have it if you use the `master` version of the lib in your IoT Agent.

There should have an official patch release (tagged `FIWARE_7.9.1`) by the end of the year.